# Return the amount of floating points in a line (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, regex, char, string-length

I am new to programming but couldn't find an answer for what I think isn't a difficult thing to do.
For a project I have to extract RGB values from a file which is specified as following:

```
#98=IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.26,0.22,0.18);
```

I have made a script with regex so far which produces this output:

```
0.26 0.22 0.18
```

Now I want to return the amount of numbers in that line as integers in front of the line like this:

```
3 0.26 0.22 0.18
```

And if extra numbers are added in that line it should add up even if it's 0

For example I want to return

```
0.26 0.22 0.18 0 0
```

as

```
5 0.26 0.22 0.18 0 0
```

The code so far:

```
import re 

IfcFile = open('IfcOpenHouse.ifc', 'r')

IfcColourData = re.compile("IFCCOLOURRGB\(\$,([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+),([\d\.]+)")

RadFile = open('IFC2RAD.rad', 'w')

for RadColourData in IfcFile:
    RGB_Data = IfcColourData.search(RadColourData)
    if RGB_Data:
        RadFile.write('mod material name' + '\n')
        RadFile.write('0' + '\n')
        RadFile.write('0' + '\n')
        g = RGB_Data.groups()
        RadFile.write('{0} {1} {2}\n\n'.format(g[0], g[1], g[2]))


IfcFile.close() 
RadFile.close()
```

Should I use len() ? And how do I specify exactly the amount of floating points and/or integers instead of all characters in that line?

Comment: where are the zeros coming from? Your regex does not capture any single digits

Comment: The zeros at the end of the line you mean? They define specular and roughness of a material in the output. Not every line has those two zeros.

Comment: yes, but where do they come from, add some example input

Comment: Sorry, I put them there 'by hand' as an example. I apologise for being confusing.

Comment: Without knowing where they come from it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: Please ignore those zeros, they are not important for now.

Comment: well then something like `(len(IfcColourData.findall(s)[0]))` will give you how many you find but considering your regex only looks for three I still don't understand

Comment: if your regex was something like `re.compile("IFCCOLOURRGB\(\$,(\d+\.\d+)")` where you find any floats then I could understand

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Answer was so obvious now I think of it.

Comment: no worries, you do know your regex will either get 3 or no floats yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is nor very much clear, for better result please clarify. See if somewhat this you are looking for

```
import re
a='IFCCOLOURRGB($,0.26,0.22,0.18,1)'
d= (re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', a))
d[0]=len(d)
for num in d:
    print num,
```

Comment: I am quite new to programming and stackoverflow. I apologise if my question wasn't that clear. Maybe I explained it a bit too elaborate with a lot of unnecessary information. Anyway my question was already answered  in the comments and I found your solution works equally well. Thank you very much.